# Mongoose Populate searching issue

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, aggregate, populate

I'm facing an issue while data fetching from database.

Here is my db collections structure:

Collection: *customers*
Document structure:

```
{
    _id: ObjectId("5f4776ec5c5e60582a3cb3a4"),
    name: "Karan",
    phone: "98767867867"
}
```

Collection: *merchants*
Document structure:

```
{
    _id: ObjectId("5f4777b45c5e60582a3cb3ab"),
    business_name: "Myntra",
    phone: "343434344"
}
```

Collection: *transactions*
Document structure:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5f477cd6d6053560bf945280"),
    "transact_from" : ObjectId("5f4776ec5c5e60582a3cb3a4"),
    "transact_from_ref" : "users",
    "transact_to" : ObjectId("5f4777b45c5e60582a3cb3ab"),
    "transact_to_ref" : "merchants",
    "transaction_amount" : 250,
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5f477cd6d6053560bf945280"),
    "transact_from" : ObjectId("5f4777b45c5e60582a3cb3ab"),
    "transact_from_ref" : "merchants",
    "transact_to" : ObjectId("5f4776ec5c5e60582a3cb3a4"),
    "transact_to_ref" : "users",
    "transaction_amount" : 250,
}
```

You can see here that in transactions records, from and to user id can be of either merchants or customers collection id.
I have to fetch data by using concept of joins:
1. populate (in find query)
2. lookup (in aggregate query)

CASE 1: When I use .find() query with populate(), the result are getting as per my expectation because I defined "refPath" instead of "ref" in Model for populating
Result:

```
[
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5f477cd6d6053560bf945280"),
        "transact_from" : "transact_to" : {
            _id: ObjectId("5f4777b45c5e60582a3cb3ab"),
            name: "Karan",
            phone: "98767867867"
        },
        "transact_from_ref" : "users",
        "transact_to" : {
            _id: ObjectId("5f4777b45c5e60582a3cb3ab"),
            business_name: "Myntra",
            phone: "343434344"
        },
        "transact_to_ref" : "merchants",
        "transaction_amount" : 250,
    }
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5f477cd6d6053560bf945280"),
        "transact_from" : {
            _id: ObjectId("5f4777b45c5e60582a3cb3ab"),
            business_name: "Myntra",
            phone: "343434344"
        },
        "transact_from_ref" : "merchants",
        "transact_to" : {
            _id: ObjectId("5f4777b45c5e60582a3cb3ab"),
            name: "Karan",
            phone: "98767867867"
        },
        "transact_to_ref" : "users",
        "transaction_amount" : 250,
    }
]
```

**Issue is Searching is not happening properly for joined fields: transact_from.name, transact_to.business_name.**

**CASE 2: When I use .aggregate() with lookup(), I'm unable to join collections dynamically. Is there any concept like "refPath" for lookup?**

Hope you are understanding my issue. Please help me if anyone has a solution?

Comment: You want to be able to search `transaction` records on the criteria present in `populated` fields, right? Like you want to fetch `transactions` by business name `myntra` or mechant name `karan`? Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: I want to serach by keyword and that needs to be check with all these: transact_to.first_name | transact_to.business_name | transact_from.first_name